# Scanner в каждом классе - рационально ли?

Tags: java

Возник такой вопрос. Имеется `5 классов` + `Main`. В классе `Main` идёт объявление потока ввода-вывода `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)`, чтобы получать значения, введенных с клавиатуры пользователем. Во всех классах существуют методы, в которых необходимо использовать `Scanner`.

Вопрос: как лучше всего использовать `Scanner`?

- Первый метод:

объявить его в каждом классе

- Второй метод:

или при вызове метода определенного класса из класса `Main`, в этом методе прописать передаваемым значением `Scanner` вот так:

```
class Building{

    public int setValue(Scanner scanner){
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: в java должны быть ссылки как в С++ нада юзать их при передачи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как создание объекта всегда ресурсоемкая операция лучше использовать пример номер 2, но Вы можете действовать на Ваше усмотрение.